# Triple integral in spherical coordinates: Finding $\phi$ limits?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

[image]

The question asks to convert to spherical coordinates then evaluate.

So for this question, I manage to get the bounds of theta and row right, but I got the bounds of phi wrong. According to the solutions, it should be $0\leq \phi\leq \pi$, but through algebraic manipulation, I got $\pi/2$. (Basically what I did is I plugged in $x= \rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$, $y = \rho \sin \phi \sin \theta$ and $z = \rho \cos \phi$ to replace all the x y and z.) Can someone tell me why this is wrong and what approach should I take to find the bounds of phi?

Comment: From looking at the limits of integration, the integral is being taken over the entire sphere.  So the limits on $\phi$ should be the full range of values for $\phi$ which is zero to $\pi$.  I can't tell from your description where you made your mistake.

Comment: The region of integration is entire sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$ and hence $0 \leq  \rho \leq a$, $0\leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $0\leq \phi \leq \pi$.

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks.